# How to change the width of a CALayer with animation from left to right?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cabasicanimation

I added a `CALayer` in a `UIView`.
And it has a fillColor.
It has also some width.
I want that layer to expand it's  width from zero to actual width with `CABasicAnimation` from left to right direction.

How to do that?

Answer (score 6):

Try animating your layer's bounds :

```
let a = CALayer()
a.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
a.position = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20)
a.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
view.layer.addSublayer(a)

let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
anim.duration = 2
anim.fromValue = NSValue(CGRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 30))
anim.toValue = NSValue(CGRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
a.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "anim")
```

It's working for me. Just don't forget to set the achor point.

Comment: I applied this code but it's width is not increasing with animation. when I run the application it's showing me the layer with it's fillcolor. And also it's starting from middle of the view.

Comment: A slight modification from stefos answer.Just replace the keypath with "bounds.size.width" and just give your width such as 0 in fromValue and 100 in toValue.Hope it helps.!

Comment: The magic of choosing whether the width animates (grows or shrinks) entirely in one direction or both directions, is in the anchorPoint of the layer you are animating. The default anchorpoint of (0.5,0.5) means that the growing or shrinking of width happens evenly on both sides. Anchorpoint of (0,0) means the layer is essentially pinned to the top left, so whatever new width it gets, the change happens on the right. That is, it matters not whether your animation key path is 'bounds' or 'bounds.size.width'. The anchor point is what determines where the change happens.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Swift 3.
To make the layer change its width from left (not from center!) to right I used the following approach:

I have layer named "layer" and I want to change it width from 0 to myWidth

```
 layer.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
 layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
 let layerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
 layerAnimation.duration = 2
 layerAnimation.fromValue = 0
 layerAnimation.toValue = myWidth
 layer.add(layerAnimation, forKey: "anim")
```

Comment: layer.anchorPoint is useful in this case, it works for me. Thank you!